# execute jmeter test plan inside cucumber step in ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, jmeter

This must be easy but I am struggling so I post it here. I am new to `Jmeter`, and I have to use it to send messages. I am testing a messaging portal which uses a core messaging application where the portal gets the data from this application. Now there are clients who connect to this messaging application and when they send messages, the application  processes it and the portal application displays it. I am using JMeter right now as a test harness simulating the client interface to send these test messages. My colleage who knows JMeter has created the .jmx file which has all the settings, the url, thread count,format of the message. All I have to do is open the .jmx file in GUI or on command line and send it. It works. I wanted this process of JMeter sending the messages automated in my cucumber step. So that when I write a step like:

```
'Given when clients sends a message'
then the step definition would be a command or script to execute the JMeter test plan.
```

I tried doing this by giving the line in my step definition:

```
system('start jmeter.bat -n -t sample.jmx ')
```

I am using ruby and the system command is the ruby way to execute external commands, in this case it is a windows command. `-n` is to run the JMeter in non-GUI mode and `-t` is to mention the .jmx file. The problem I have here is, anytime I run the JMeter in non-GUI mode, it opens a terminal, executes and the control stays there. So when I use this script in my cucumber steps, the control stays there in terminal and my cucumber scenarios fails. 
How can I do this in a different way so that the JMeter test plan gets executed in the background or I get the control back to my cucumber step?

Note: I may have a solution using the `ruby-jmeter` gem : https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter but I am not finding a way how to simply execute this using the gem. Here in the gem he tells of running the test plan locally or on flood-io but not at a different url. In my case the url is an IP address where the messaging application is listening and I use JMS publisher in JMeter to send messages via GUI. I created the .jmx file using the GUI and the same can be used in command line successfully. Please let me know of any solutions.

Comment: As far as I can tell `ruby-jmeter` is a gem to *generate* `.jmx` files, not to execute them. You *can* execute files you generate through the ruby DSL, but not arbitrary ones generated outside of it. It mentions running `JMeter` in headless mode, maybe you can search for that?

Comment: Looks like the ruby-jmeter gem doesnt support JMS publisher which is required for my application. Anything i use, it converts to HTTPrequest. i ended up running the jmeter as command line in ruby code. had tough time in suppressing the dos black window of the external command in ruby & redirecting the warning jmeter creates by running as command line in my code!!